# Deploy XConnect certificate to ASEv2

Tags: xconnect, arm-template

Currently I am deploying Sitecore 9 infrastructure at our customer, which hosts web apps at Azure App Service Environments v2 (ASEv2).

I am using standard Sitecore ARM templates, with slight modifications (I do not need to deploy serverFarms, as they are already in ASEv2) and here comes a problem: web apps could not find certificate, deployed in RG by ARM template. If I add this certificate manually to web app, it got deployed to RG, but this time - it seems to be installed on ASEv2 somehow and all web apps in this ASE could load my certificate.

Is there an ARM/Powershell example on how to deploy PFX certificate at ASEv2, so it will be available to web apps in this ASE for loading?